# Gwt и javascript

Tags: gwt, java

Всем привет! Мне нужно встроить гугл карту в gwt модуль. На странице будет отображена карта и еще нное количество gwt компонентов. Гугл карта должна взаимодействовать с этими компонентами. Допустим при клике отображать текущие координаты в компоненте Label, либо при клике на маркер открывать какое-нибудь вслывающее окно (gwt) и отображать информацию по маркеру. Еще допустим есть таблица в базе данных, которая содержит координаты маркеров. При открытии страницы метод пробегается по таблице в базе данных, берет координаты маркера и рисует его на карте. Теперь вопрос: т.к вся работа с google картами происходит через javascript, как быть? Где-то видела, что можно работать с java кодом из javascript, и наооборот. Неужели мне весь проект придется делать подобные манипуляции? С gwt работаю недавно, так что простите, если что-то не так. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

> Где-то видела, что можно работать с java кодом из javascript, и наооборот.

Можно, это называется JSNI.

> Неужели мне весь проект придется делать подобные манипуляции?

Обычно пишется класс-обертка над JS-кодом и все взаимодействия идут далее через него.

Более того, такие [обертки уже есть](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/MapsGettingStarted).